# Why can't the dispatch function of a useState hook be passed directly into an onClick handler?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

```
const Counter = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  // return <button onClick={setCount(count + 1)}>{count}</button>;
  return <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>{count}</button>;
};
```

I'm aware that the commented out line causes an infinite loop but I want to know why that's the case. Isn't the `setCount` dispatch function invoked only on click?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the expression within a `{}` in JSX is *evaluated* and then its result is used where that `{}` was — in this case, as the value of the `onClick` property. So `onClick={setCount(count + 1)}` *evaluates* `setCount(count + 1)` (calling the function, which will set the state) and then uses the resulting value for the `onClick`. Since calling it sets the state, that causes re-rendering, which does it again endlessly.

Your other version creates a function when the JSX is evaluated without calling it, which is why it works.

Answer (score 1):

when you do this:

```
onClick={setCount(count + 1)}
```

you are calling that method during render.

I don't see the infinite loop, but you are calling that setCount for each render causing a re render.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I thought he meant an infinite loop of a recursive setCount